# android acitivitygroup button onClick make applicatoin crash

Tags: android, button, spinner, android-tabhost, activitygroup

So im developing a android application and im using a tabhost.
To handle the activity's i created a activitygroup from every tab.

From these "parent" activity's i go to child acivity's.

on this child acitivy i have a page with a spinner and a button.

First the button was working but when i clicked on the spinner the application would crash.
To fix this i had to change

```
setContentView(R.layout.sho_add_exercise_event);
```

to

```
View contentView = LayoutInflater.from(getParent()).inflate(R.layout.show_add_exercise_event, null);
setContentView(contentView);
```

now my spinner is working but when i click on the button the application will crash.

This is the log output

```
04-05 12:42:58.890: E/AndroidRuntime(4485): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-05 12:42:58.930: E/AndroidRuntime(4485): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onClickAdd(View) in the activity
04-05 12:42:58.930: E/AndroidRuntime(4485):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2016)
04-05 12:42:58.930: E/AndroidRuntime(4485):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2344)
04-05 12:42:58.930: E/AndroidRuntime(4485):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4133)
04-05 12:42:58.930: E/AndroidRuntime(4485):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6510)
04-05 12:42:58.930: E/AndroidRuntime(4485):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3672)
04-05 12:42:58.930: E/AndroidRuntime(4485):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
04-05 12:42:58.930: E/AndroidRuntime(4485):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
04-05 12:42:58.930: E/AndroidRuntime(4485):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
04-05 12:42:58.930: E/AndroidRuntime(4485):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
04-05 12:42:58.930: E/AndroidRuntime(4485):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
04-05 12:42:58.930: E/AndroidRuntime(4485):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent

04-05 12:42:58.930: E/AndroidRuntime(4485): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onClickAdd
04-05 12:42:58.930: E/AndroidRuntime(4485):     at java.lang.ClassCache.findMethodByName(ClassCache.java:308)
04-05 12:42:58.930: E/AndroidRuntime(4485):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1007)
04-05 12:42:58.930: E/AndroidRuntime(4485):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2013)
04-05 12:42:58.930: E/AndroidRuntime(4485):     ... 37 more
```

EDIT:

i got this method in the activity but he doesnt find the method becaus i did
View contentView = LayoutInflater.from(getParent()).inflate(R.layout.show_add_exercise_event, null);
    setContentView(contentView);

Hope some1 can help me :D!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I deleted the onClick in the xml file.
And added a setOnClickListener in my java code.

This did the job :) hope this helps some1 else out to!

Answer (score 1):

Message is self-explanatory: `Could not find a method onClickAdd(View) in the activity`

Declare a method with this event:

```
public void onClickAdd(View v)
{
   .......
   .......
}
```

Because somewhere you have declared onClickAdd() method for **Add** button i think.

Comment: i got this method in my acitivy but becaus i did 

View contentView = LayoutInflater.from(getParent()).inflate(R.layout.show_add_exercise_event, null);
setContentView(contentView); 

he doesnt find the method :/